# Kendo grid export to excel -Right to left support

Tags: angularjs, excel

I am using Kendo grid for Angular js and export the content to excel using client side export feature provided by Kendo .

I want the same feature to be supporting RTL . While exporting to excel , i achieved the same using below code

sheet.rows.cells.reverse();
sheet.rows.cells.hAlign = "right";

But here ,Even if the content was changing and reverse it's direction ,Coulmn numbers and column identifiers like A,B,C are still staring from Left.

Any body ,please give a suggestion if you have faced such an issue earlier.

Regards
Subin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the RTL pack using below code . This pack will do the rest of reversing of content and headers for you.

import { RTL } from '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n';

Please read below article for more

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/globalization/#toc-right-to-left-support

Comment: can you explain more how you solve this?